# JAVA: how to create button with name parameter of the method?

Tags: java, swing, methods, jbutton

I want to write a method that allows creating of JButton with different name.

I wish I could send a parameter name and a button title.

```
AddButtonMethod("name", "title");
```

methode:

```
private void AddButtonMethod(String name, String title){


            JButton name = new JButton(title);

            name.addActionListener(ecouteurBouton);

            add(name);

    }
```

and I want the new button as the name that received patranetre "name"

Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

Please understand that variable names are a much less important than you may realize and hardly even exist after code is compiled. What is much more important and what is key are variable references -- the ability to gain access to a particular object at a particular point in your program, and you can have Strings refer to objects easily by using a Map such as a HashMap. For instance

```
// in the variable declaration section of the class
private Map<String, JButton> buttonMap = new HashMap<>();

// your method should be named addButton, not AddButton
private void addButton(String name, String title){
   JButton button = new JButton(title);
   button.addActionListener(ecouteurBouton);
   buttonMap.put(name, button);
   add(button);
}
```